# How can add comment next to html tag - <div/ > <!-- comments -->

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, comments, text-editor, vscode-extensions

I need to know the shortcut to add this comment `<!-- -->`, Apart from `Ctrl + /`

Comment: Please explain context of what you want to to do, for example which code editor or IDE you are using?

Comment: @mhrabiee I'm using VS Code for react development. And usually for user understanding we'll add comment line for each modules inside Html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `VS Code` you can use [Snippet Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) plugin.

So the steps will be like this:

- Install Snippet Creator
- Write `<!-- -->` some where in your code.
- Select it and right click on it and select "Command Palette".
- Write "Create Snippet".
- Enter snippet shortcut. (for example `cmt')
- Enter snippet description. (for example `HTML comment')

Then you can use write `cmt` then press `tab` button and it will print `<!-- -->`